# Apache/PHP configuration setting the wrong permissions on PHP generated files

Tags: apache-2.2, ubuntu-10.04, php5, file-permissions

I have an Ubuntu server running a LAMP stack, and set up the permissions on `/var/www` such that all developers in our organisation are members of the www-data group, and the directory permissions are 2775 (`rwxrwsr-x`), file permissions should all be 664 - I've also set the default umask in `/etc/profile` to be 0002.

This all works great, except that any file created by PHP on the server only has permissions 644 (`rw-r--r--`)...

I'm trying to find something in PHP or Apache configuration (probably PHP) that sets new files to be 664 by default - is there such a beast?

Update:

I found the following information at http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=549457

Adding the line:

```
umask 0002
```

to `/etc/apache2/envvars` and restarting the server should work.

I restarted, without error, but it doesn't seem to have changed a thing. My PHP-generated files are still not group writeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried using [PHP's umask() function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.umask.php)?  It's very possible that PHP enforces a set of file permissions of its own...

Comment: Thanks - interesting to see that, but I was hoping for a configuration option...